# How to view non-stored fields per document?

Tags: solr

I have a field like this:

```
<field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
```

Using [`LukeRequestHandler`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) I can view only statistics of the indexed terms, I can view indexed terms per document if `stored="true"`. [`TermsComponent`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) can show only frequencies of terms, I cannot view terms per document.

Is it possibly to look inside the inverted index without setting `stored="true"` and reindexing Solr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to view the indexed terms for a single document, you need to use the full Luke application, not the LukeRequestHandler.  You would need to copy the index folder from your Solr data directory to another location, then open it in Luke.

There is however a workaround within solr itself - do a search that will return just the one document, and facet on the field you want to examine.  Every term in the index for that field on that document will be an entry in the facet output.  Here is a full sample URL for this kind of search:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=id:1234&facet.field=status&facet.limit=-1&facet.mincount=1&facet=true&facet.method=enum
```

If you decide to go the Luke route, you can step through your index (or search for an individual document) and view just one document.

The official Luke page is here, but it only supports up through 4.0-ALPHA:
http://code.google.com/p/luke/

You can find Luke for versions beyond 4.0-ALPHA here:
https://java.net/projects/opengrok/downloads

There is an effort underway to absorb Luke into the Lucene/Solr source code as a module, so it will always be current and released at the same time as each Lucene/Solr version.

Comment: Thank you for the hint on facets. It works! I tried Luke, but it does not show non-stored fields. I have found the document. On the `Documents` tab near the `status` field it is written `<not present or not stored>`. It is present, I've checked it using your URL.

Comment: There is supposed to be a way in Luke to see the indexed terms for a field, whether it's stored or not.  I'm looking at one of my indexes right now with the 5.4 version of Luke, and I cannot figure out how to actually do it.

Comment: If you click the "Reconstruct and Edit" button, then you will see an attempt by Luke to reconstruct the original document based on the indexed terms, but it is not the same as an actual list of terms.  Depending on the analysis used, it may not be able to show you the *exact* information in the index.